# Find what packages are installed from a repository

Tags: command-line, apt, search

I'm trying to find what packages I have installed from a repository using terminal commands.

I found a post somewhere saying I could use `aptitude search "?origin (<repository>) ?installed"`, but I couldn't get it working. I tried searching for a packages that came from ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa and got nothing with these:

```
aptitude search "?origin (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/) ?installed"
aptitude search "?origin (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/) ?installed"
aptitude search "?origin (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ raring/main) ?installed"
```

It would be nice if I could get something that works with PPAs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In brackets, you should use only the name of the repository, not the URI or something else. For example in your case:

```
aptitude search "?origin (ubuntu-wine) ?installed"
```

Run `apt-cache policy` to see the repositories and the names (aka origin, `o`) of those:

```
$ apt-cache policy | grep wine
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-wine,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Wine Team PPA,c=main,b=i386
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-wine,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Wine Team PPA,c=main,b=amd64
```

Since the search string is a regex pattern matched anywhere in the string, you can use a convenient substring like `ubuntu-wine`, or even just `wine`.

See also: [How can I get a list of all repositories and PPAs from the command line into an install script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/148932/147044)

Comment: This did not list packages for me: `aptitude search "?origin (multiverse) ?installed"` - shouldn't it? ("multiverse" is enabled)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel no, but use `aptitude search "?section (multiverse) ?installed"`, instead.

Comment: On my system, this seems to list packages that are installed and also available in the specified repository, irrespective of whether they were actually installed _from_ that repository.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a shell script I wrote to display packages installed from different origins excluding Ubuntu. It uses common `dpkg -l` output format. It works faster than `aptitude` solutions.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Print packages installed from different origins.
# Exclude standard Ubuntu repositories.

grep -H '^Origin:' /var/lib/apt/lists/*Release | grep -v ' Ubuntu$' | sort -u \
| while read -r line; do
    origin=${line#* }    
    echo $origin:
    
    list=${line%%:*}
    sed -rn 's/^Package: (.*)$/\1/p' ${list%_*Release}*Packages | sort -u \
    | xargs -r dpkg -l 2>/dev/null | grep '^.i '
    echo
 done
```

Some packages may be available from more than one repository. Run `apt policy [pkgname]` to check from which repository the current package is actually installed from.

Note that there may also be installed packages that have no such origin available, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/98223/21005) to find them.

Comment: This is the only script which actually worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: I tried this script, but it also listed Ubuntu packages. Any idea why?

Comment: @technastic_tc Could you run the line starting by `grep` excluding `\`. Upload the result in pastebin and share the link to it.

Comment: @jarno https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116028/room-for-technastic-tc-and-jarno

Answer (score 5):

Origin is not URL of repository. To find Origin of repository look for file in `/var/lib/apt/lists/` ending with Release.

For example

```
grep "Origin" /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_wheezy_Release
```

Will show:

```
Origin: Dropbox.com
```

So `aptitude search "?origin(dropbox.com) ?installed"` will show me installed package from dropbox repository.

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for.

Comment: You might need to escape some characters in the origin name, if they are special in regular expression.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchOrigin

Answer (score 3):

From the command line If you like to do means

```
awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*PPA-FIRST-PART*PPA-SECOND-PART*Packages
```

for example : All there are packages from noobslab

```
 jai@frank-Jai:~$ awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*noobslab*Packages

python-logilab-common
synapse
ubuntuone-client
python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
ubuntuone-client-gnome
python-ubuntuone-client
lives
libweed0
libweed-dev
lives-data
converseen
minitube
libsyncdaemon-1.0-1
libsyncdaemon-1.0-dev
ubuntu-sso-client
python-ubuntuone-devtools
ubuntuone-dev-tools
ubuntuone-control-panel
python-ubuntuone-control-panel
synapse-dbg
gir1.2-syncdaemon-1.0
libweed-dbg
lives-dbg
umplayer
umplayer-translations
libgranite-dev
deepin-software-center
ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
python-dirspec
rhythmbox-ubuntuone
python-ubuntu-sso-client
ubuntu-sso-client-qt
python-ubuntu-sso-client.tests
granite-demo
ubuntuone-client-proxy
python-oauthlib
slidewall
python3-dirspec
python3-oauthlib
ubuntuone-client-data
libgranite1
libgranite1-dbg
gir1.2-granite-1.0
libgranite-common
curlew
fbmessenger
open-as-administrator
indicator-synapse
indicator-synapse-dbg
wallpaper-manager
awoken-icon-theme
malys-uniblack
malys-uniblue
malys-ex
acyl-icons
nitrux-icons
piratunbu-icons
azenis-green-icons
nouvegnome-color
nouvegnome-gray
hi-lights-icons
matrilineare
zoncolor-icons
royal-linux-icons
elementary-icons
myhumanity
myelementary
glass-icons
osx-nostalgie
sky-blue-cinnamon
sky-blue-gnome
sky-blue-unity
wine-blue-remix
lubuntubox
windows7-icons
appleart-icons
magical-lights-icons
colored-plastic-icons
numix-utouch-icon-theme
ubudao-style
artnet-icons
high-delight-icons
snow-sabre-icons
trevilla-icons
aery-icons
ambiance-blue
zukitwo
gnomishbeige-theme
salience-theme
zukiwi
gnomishgray
delorean-dark
smoothly-theme
ambiance-ds-blue
ambiance-lime
gnomishdark
zukitwo-cupertino-gs
mediterranean-theme
elementaryish
borderline
boje
wow-2
zoncolor-themes
omg-suite
simplex
leopard-steel
dorian-theme
daylight
adwaita-elements
uncomplicated
trevilla-jmhzonedark
trevilla-dark
trevilla-white
trevilla-whiteblue
trevilla-whiteorange
trevilla-white2
ambiancep-set
ambiance-crunchy
trevilla-gray
siva-series-gtk
cobibird
elegant-brit
mac-ithemes-noobslab
mac-icons-noobslab
ubuntu-touch-themes
windows8-theme
bigfootblue-cinnamon
windows8-cinnamon
eliza1-cinnamon
bigfootred-cinnamon
plus1-theme
futura
blo-theme
darkair-theme
plane-gtk3
deepin-gtk-theme
nokto-theme
numix-theme
neptune-theme
trevilla-themes
jai@frank-Jai:~$
```

[Credit goes here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-list-packages-from-ppa.html)

Comment: I got this error:
bash: awk: No such file or directory

Comment: @Enkouyami whats the ls of /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: Here's a link to what I got http://pastebin.com/AmiH9E9n

Comment: @Enkouyami oops sorry , I mean the command what you have entered

Comment: @ rajagenupula: awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*<awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*webupd8team*haguichi*Packages

Comment: @Enkouyami Ok this in not about command , placement. do as  `awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*haguichi*webupd8team*Packages`

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use Y-PPA  manager. Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Then open your Unity dash and search with Y -PPA and then open the Icon.

[image]

Click at manage PPAs as shown in the image and then select one PPA and it will give you the details of the PPA and Its packages.

Comment: Could you provide some instructions for using Y-PPA manager?

Comment: @Seth my friend. done.

Comment: I was looking for a command line solution.

Comment: This solution is neither command line nor answers the main question - how to list packages installed from a given repo? It only shows ALL packages available from a PPA.