# How do I list all installed packages and their repositories?

Tags: package-management, repository, esm

I have a 16.04 server that I haven't been able to upgrade to 20.04, so I'm considering [Extended Security Maintenance](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/ESM/16.04#Maintained_Packages) for it.

The linked page says that ESM only applies to the 'main' and 'restricted' repositories.  In order to know if ESM will work, then, I need to determine what packages are installed that are outside of these repos.  The easiest way to do this would be to produce a list of all installed packages along with the repo each belongs to.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Alternative: Look at it the other way around: Take the applications that you use, determine the package they came from, and then the repository/pocket that provides that package.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1133053/15811 seems to do what you want

Comment: @user535733 The problem there is that I don't know all of the packages I've ever used.  It's a five-year-old machine, I could easily have installed something and forgotten about it.  I need to be able to identify everything, whether I can name it in advance or not.

Comment: @Rinzwind  I can't even read that, much less can I trust it.  I can start trying to parse it, but it's going to take days.  I was hoping Ubuntu provided some more natural sort of tool for this.

Comment: `ubuntu-support-status` will tell you the answers you want, have you tried?

Comment: @guiverc  I didn't know about this, but I think it's similar to what I've been looking for.  I can't be sure, though.  If I run it, it says the bulk of my system is unsupported, which is correct because it's 16.04.  What I need to know is which packages **would remain unsupported** on ESM; i.e., packages that are outside the 'main' and 'restricted' repos.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't show me that.  There's no `man` page, and the only [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/check-support-status.1.html) are unhelpful.

Comment: I just had a look using `ubuntu-support-status` on a *xenial* box and yeah now everything shows as unsupported.. ie. a very different result as to what it provided on 29-April-2021 *or before* (where 'universe' etc. packages showed in 'unsupported' whilst 'main' etc where listed in two 'supported' groupings....  all that gone as everything is now in 'unsupported').   The python script maybe could be modified, to do what you want, but it no longer does exactly what you want as you've missed the intended window of that tool (ie. whilst the product was still supported)

Comment: @Rinzwind I gave up about halfway through and ran the script anyway.  It doesn't even remotely tell me what I'm asking for.  It just lists a few packages in some format that isn't explained, and then it lists them again.  It doesn't identify all packages on my system, and it doesn't tell me any repositories.  So that was two fucking days wasted thanks to "Free community support!"